# Dependents field is not hidden in my form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field

I want use dependents field in my form but my input is not hidde
I followed this tutorial https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/dependent-form-fields

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require now-ui-kit
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require moment.min
//= require nouislider.min
//= require jquery.bootstrap.wizard
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require paper-bootstrap-wizard
//= require underscore
//= require dependent-fields
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  DependentFields.bind()
});
```

My view

```
<%= simple_form_for @contrat do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= f.input :num_mandat, label: 'Numero Mandat' %>
      <%= f.input :mandat_type, label: 'Type Mandat' %>
      <%= f.input :client_type, label: 'Type de personne', collection: ['Physique', 'Morale'], id: 'client_choice' %>
      <%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'data-select': 'client_choice', 'data-option-value': 'Physique'} do %>
        <%= f.input :sexe_phi, collection: ['Mme', 'Mr'] %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Valider" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your form like below.

```
<%= simple_form_for @contrat do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :num_mandat, label: 'Numero Mandat' %>
    <%= f.input :mandat_type, label: 'Type Mandat' %>
    <%= f.input :client_type, label: 'Type de personne', collection: ['Physique', 'Morale'], id: 'client_choice' %>
    <%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'select-id': 'client_choice', 'option-value': 'Physique'} do %>
      <%= f.input :sexe_phi, collection: ['Mme', 'Mr'] %>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Valider" %>
<% end %>
```

You haven't implemented content_tag properly.

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'select-id': 'client_choice', 'option-value': 'Physique'} do %>
  <%= f.input :sexe_phi, collection: ['Mme', 'Mr'] %>
<% end %>
```

Look at [here](https://github.com/vollnhals/dependent-fields-rails#depending-on-a-select-element) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dipak, i change my code but its still not working